# How to change MySQLYog error message language

Tags: php, mysql, sql, settings, mysql-error-1064

I am using SQLyog ultimate for MySQL.

The problem is when my query has any error, the error message thrown by SQLYog is not in english. For e.g.:

```
Error Code: 1052
Champ: 'fn' dans field list est ambigu
```

So is there any setting I need to change to get error messages in english?

**Software name and version** : `SQLyog Ultimate - MySQL GUI v10.00 Beta1`

Answer (score 2):

In SQLyog run this query after that all the error messages will come in english language

```
SET lc_messages = 'en_US';
```

For permanently resetting the language, open mysql configuration file `my.ini` and look for the `lc-messages=` and change it

```
lc-messages=en_US
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to change it by navigating to the `Tools > Change Language` option.

[image]

Comment: i checked that, it is for `UI` and language setting is `english`